# Netty tcnative with OpenSSL and supported groups (elliptic curves)

Tags: java, openssl, netty, elliptic-curve, ecdhe

I have a server using JRE8, netty 4.1.x and netty-tcnative 2.0.36. By default `SslProvider.OPENSSL` is configured.

```
SslContextBuilder contextBuilder = SslContextBuilder.forServer(keyMngrFactory)
                    .sslProvider(SslProvider.OPENSSL)
                    .enableOcsp(true);
```

Server is configured with TLS 1.2 and TLS_ECDHE_RSA* cipher suites.

I need to be able to restrict (whitelist) the elliptic curves (supported_groups extension) used for ECDHE ephemeral key exchange during SSL handshake. However, with `SslProvider.OPENSSL`, server does not seem to honour the system property `-Djdk.tls.namedGroups`. Instead, server always uses P-256 for ephemeral key exchange.

If I switch to `SslProvider.JDK`, above system property (`-Djdk.tls.namedGroups`) is reflecting during ECDHE ephemeral key exchange. However, I can't switch my production application to use JDK provider.

I came across https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/567 - Based on this, I believe there is no support to restrict the supported_groups extension. But not sure if there is any alternative approach.

My queries:

1. While using `SslProvider.OPENSSL` with netty-tcnative, can we restrict the elliptic curves (supported group/named group) to be used for key exchange?
2. If yes, how to configure the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neety-tcnative has been updated through this PR - https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/pull/661 to support this feature.